# Flux through sphere using divergence

Tags: calculus, divergence-operator

> A vector field $F=yi+2j+k$ exists over a surface S defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$ bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ in first octant. Find flux of $F$ over the surface indicated (Ans:$9(1+3\pi/4)$)

calculating  the divergence using gauss theorem, we see that $$\iint_{S}\mathbf  F\cdot dS=\iiint_V\operatorname{div}(\mathbf F)\,dV$$
but $\operatorname{div}(\mathbf F)=0,$ so the flux over the surface is $0$.

Now calculating flux over the three surfaces of sphere in xy, xz and yz respectively.
$S_{xy}=9π/4$, $S_{xz}=9π/2$ and $S_{yz}=0$

Putting these all together, we have
$$
  \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = 27π/4
$$

What am I doing wrong?